# How do I select server install from an Ubuntu boot CD with both desktop and server present?

Tags: ubuntu, installation

Hi I purchased 'The Official Ubuntu Server Book 2nd Edition' which comes complete with a boot CD labelled as 'Desktop Edition and 32-bit Server' (10.04 LTS). I can boot from the disc but I can't seem to get to the server edition, it only gives me the desktop installation screen.

The book is no help it just starts from the server install screen with no mention of the desktop edition. I want to create a LAMP server and I've found the `boot:` prompt but have no idea how to initiate the server install.

What command do I need to enter at the boot prompt to start the server install?

I've accidentally installed the desktop edition before I realised it wasn't server. Can I just install server from that?

**EDIT:** From the Desktop install screen I see this command;
`file=/cdrom/preseed/ubuntu.seed boot=casper only-ubiquity initrd=/casper/initrd.lz quiet splash --`

Examining the CD I've found the `/preseed/ubuntu-server.seed` file but switching to the boot prompt and entering the above command with the server seed didn't workas it tells me it can't find that kernel image.

**EDIT:** Opening boot prompt and then hitting return got me to the boot menu so I could press TAB to edit the commmands and see that I needed `/casper/vmlinuz` before the command. This attempted the install but it failed and I'm back at the desktop now trying to work out why the install failed.

Comment: Did you try pressing <Tab>?

Comment: @ignacio Just tried that at the desktop install screen and no joy, been looking around the install cd and confused where the server files might be.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like the book comes with *two disks*: Ubuntu Server 10.04 LTS 64-bit CD, and Ubuntu 10.04 LTS 32-bit DVD.  Could it be that you're using the wrong disk?  If all else fails, you can always [download and burn the disk yourself from Ubuntu's site](http://www.ubuntu.com/server/get-ubuntu/download).

EDIT: The book should have come with *two disks* according to the [Amazon page for the book](http://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/0137081332).  The two disks are:

- Ubuntu Server 10.04 LTS 64-bit CD, and
- Ubuntu 10.04 LTS 32-bit DVD

If you bought this used, chances are that the original owner only included one of the two disks.  Otherwise, you don't have the whole package.  It is also highly doubtful that they put both the server and desktop versions on the disk, so I think you're trying to access something that's just not there.

Keep in mind Ubuntu Server and Desktop Editions are the same OS with different packages installed by default--there's nothing stopping you from installing the desktop edition and removing X11/Gnome/etc. to imitate the server edition.

EDIT2: To remove the desktop packages, you'll want to switch to a virtual terminal (Ctrl-Alt-F1, for example) and run the following:

```
apt-get remove --purge ubuntu-desktop
apt-get autoremove
apt-get install ubuntu-server
```

I believe these are the correct package names.  The first command, removing ubuntu-desktop, should remove all your gnome dependencies.  The next time you start up, the grub boot menu should now contain a server entry.  As with any major changes, make sure you backup anything you can't stand to lose! :)  Good luck, and looking forward to hearing how it goes.

Comment: Desktop installed fine from the media and I've now found the unbuntu-server.seed on the disk. The machine is old and won't boot from USB and I don't have any blank CDs to burn a boot image from a download right now. Just seems odd to sell a book about server and yet that be so difficult to install from the provided media.

Comment: I updated my answer with more info, but like I said, it sounds like you didn't get everything you were supposed to get.

Comment: Thanks @Redmumba I bought the book brand new so definitely have the right contents. I was wondering what the difference between Desktop and Server would actually be, I can work from the Desktop install for sure. I was hoping to get the LAMP packages installed from the Server Role menu the book mentions but I just found a note in the book about the `sudo tasksel` command so I can go and try that now.

Comment: You CAN do everything you do on the server on the desktop edition.  The only difference will be that you have a GUI and a slightly different kernel--although you can also remove the desktop install.  I added these instructions to my answer.